# How to ignore routes from camel-metrics?

Tags: apache-camel

I am sending metric data from camel-metrics to AWS CloudWatch. While doing so some camel routes (which collect the metrics, handle errors) are distorting my data.

So I want these routes to still work, but to be excluded from Camel Metrics. Is there an option/attribute to do so? I did not find anything related to that.

My other guess is that Camel Metrics has an Interceptor SpringBean which collects the data and saves to JMX. If I could override that method and exclude the unnecessary routes by hand, that would be fine too. So is there such an interceptor, what is the name of it?

**EDIT:**

I found MetricsRoutePolicyFactory - which creates the metrics policy for routes. I filtered out the unnecessary routes from the metrics policy, so they are not collected, however somehow they still get to jmx.

**EDIT2:**

I figured out, that Camel saves metrics to JMX by default, (at least the ones I use: routes, and context) so it has nothing to do with camel-metrics.

Comment: Why can't you filter those unwanted routes yourself, eg from camel-metrics -> filter -> aws cw

Comment: @ClausIbsen Because camel-metrics save metrics of the whole context too, which I also monitor. And these metics are distorted with error handlers etc. in the JMX.

Answer (score 2):

Camel JMX stores JMX data for all routes and CamelContext etc. You cannot really say only for this route, and not for that. There is a JIRA ticket AFAIR about being able to turn on JMX per route. But today its not implemented.

However an alternative is to configure Camel JMX to only register mbeans if an id has been explicit assigned. Then you can use assign ids for the routes you want monitored. And then leave the other routes with a route id assigned. However if you need JMX stats for processors as well, you need to assign ids to them too.

See the option *onlyRegisterProcessorWithCustomId* at 
http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html

Comment: Thanks! Can you please help me with that? How do I add onlyRegisterProcessorWithCustomId to Spring? I guess there is a prefix for that, but I am not sure what, I can't see it from the docs

Comment: It does not seem to work with the system property for me. I can see the IDless routes as "route1", "route2"... in JMX at MBeans